# What is 'slop' in ApproximateTimeSynchronizer?

Tags: ros, message-filter, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going through the message filters in ros noetic and came across the following class.

```
class message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer(fs, queue_size, slop, allow_headerless=False, reset=False)
```

What does the parameter `slop` stand for?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364729/what-is-%27slop%27-in-approximatetimesynchronizer?/) by [paul_shuvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/37881/paul_shuvo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2020-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From this [documentation](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/12eaf946597739e833b2300ef28bb079f248a9e1/utilities/message_filters/src/message_filters/__init__.py) line 237:

> "slop" parameter in the constructor that defines the delay (in seconds) with which messages can be synchronized

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-04**:
I would point to the [Python API documentation](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/message_filters/html/python/index.html?highlight=slop#message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer) for `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer` instead.

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-11-04**:
Very good point, thank you!

**Comment by [BCJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/55777/bcj/) on 2021-06-14**:
Hello, however this param is missing in the C++ API. May I know why?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-14**:
Please see #q375572 (among others, such as #q284758). The comments point to  `setMaxIntervalDuration(..)`.

And in the future: please don't post comments with follow-up questions under questions with accepted answers from `N` years ago. Your comment will have almost 0 visibility.